# How many http socket connections does Google Cloud Messaging provide?

Tags: http, google-cloud-messaging, chrome-gcm

I'm using GCM to send messages from my (3rd Party) application to android app. I want to know how many different instances of my 3rd party application I can run with the same Project Credentials.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read the GCM documentation more than once, and there is no mention of any limit on the number of connections per credentials. And since the HTTP GCM protocol is synchronous, and you get a response for each request, you don't have to keep the HTTP connection open across multiple HTTP requests, so there really shouldn't be any issue with the number of connections.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Eran. What about the case when I want to push notifications asynchronously on an open socket connection. Will I have to use XMPP in this case or is there any other way to do this? Also how many socket connections GCM can handle in the case when I use XMPP?